# servlet-filters precedence

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, servlet-filters, operator-precedence

Since since filters are chained one after another, I cannot know when to remove MDC/NDC (log4j) information.
Which is the topmost servlet filter?

I have one defined inside deploy/jboss-portal-ha.sar/portal-server.war/WEB-INF/Web.xml
and several others spread around the application server.

What's the rule of precedence in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Servlet filters are chained in the order that they are defined within your web.xml, and should be specific to each web application context - which is almost always synonymous with a web application archive (WAR).

Details around the exact ordering used (which takes both the `<url-pattern>` and `<servlet-name>` elements into account) are documented in the Java Servlet Specification under "SRV.6.2.4 Configuration of Filters in a Web Application", available for download at http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/.

Comment: Note that the question is not about ordering of filters in a single `web.xml`, but about ordering of filters spread over multiple `web.xml`s.